# Bin deploying MVC4 as a virtual directory to an MVC3 website entry in IIS6 cannot load assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, iis-6

I'm trying to bin deploy a MVC4 application and have run into an issue that's left me pretty confused.

I have a web site entry in IIS6 that is running an MVC3 application currently. The new application I'm trying to deploy is setup as a virtual directory under it.

When you browse to the application it's throwing this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, **Version=1.0.0.0**,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The bin folder in the new application has this file:

> System.Web.Helpers.dll **Version 2.0.20710.0**

The error seems to indicate that the application is trying to load version 1.0 of the assembly, and getting the version 2.0 file causing it to throw with the manifest mismatch.

What I don't understand is why it would try to load the version 1.0 file in the first place. I could be wrong though.

Has anyone seen this before, or could offer any advice in resolving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these binding redirects cleared up the problem.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```